# Get Information by Curl and Api Facebook Graph

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, ads

I wrote this code for information about ad company:

```
    public function getStatAd($id_company, $time_range, $fields, $access_token){
    $curl = new Curl\Curl();
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/" . $id_company;                       
    $postData = "&time_range=" . $time_range                                             
                               . "&fields=" 
                               . $fields                                                
                               . "&access_token=" . $access_token;                       

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);                                                            

    curl_close($ch);

    //var_dump($output);
}
```

And call this method:

```
getStatAd(
   $_POST['id_company'],
   "'since':2017-08-10,'until':2017-08-17",  // to do dynamic
   "reach,impressions,clicks,spend", 
   "token"
   );
```

"var_dump($output);"  :

> {"error": {"message":"Invalid
>   parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_data":
>   {"blame_field_specs":[["account_id"]]},
>   "error_subcode":1885316,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Disabled
>   accounts can't create or edit ads", "error_user_msg":"Only active
>   accounts can create or edit ads.","fbtrace_id":""}}

Where is my mistake in the code? Tell me please. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn’t look like a code issue, but simply a problem with the ad account you are using there ...

Comment: I change this: $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/insights" and get new exception: Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation...

Comment: Yeah well that happens if you just change stuff willy-nilly and without any logic ... This request makes absolutely no sense whatsoever, because you need to specify an object first, before you can access any insights.

Comment: Have you use proper API keys and secrets along with Access token?

Comment: i use for the test id 6070056173732, token EAAHxQfI1uiIBAEcAqSMhQPE51ZCwVgItvdTfcqiBPI1LUxUINAl7zR0pRqbKaDwZCDfHvSHJZBV1P2avk2unjgwvfk57aREf74rQS1udtKUX2ps2zTGy6Au2yGTKuOrgLcRQ4L2ZBV48Xq73RIwD43PxtXkODzDNZB4LqBScMWwZDZD , but not api

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with curl. After trying diffrent ways the only solution so far withour token errors or bad requests it's using file_get_contents:

```
$graph_url_post = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$vPostID."?fields=full_picture,type&access_token=" . $vToken;

$post_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_post), true);
```

Where vToken it's your access token made like `$app_id . "|" . $app_secret`